# Chartjs how to show scale label horizontally

Tags: chart.js

Due to very poor documentation (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) I decided to ask Chart.js community this question.

**How can I change the angle of the scale label?**

This is my actual view

[image]

I would like to make those labels horizontal (see red labels how it should be).
The config is:

```js
yAxes: [{
  display: true,
  scaleLabel: {
    display: true,
    labelString: [this.label, this.valueUnit],
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  afterFit: function(scaleInstance) {
    scaleInstance.width = 120;
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a second y-axis that is responsible for drawing the scale label horizontally.

The single `yAxis.ticks` label can be left aligned by defining [`mirror: true`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration) together with some [`padding`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration).

```
ticks: {
  mirror: true,
  padding: 60,
  ...
```

To make the tick label visible on the chart area, the same padding needs to be defined left of the [chart layout](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html).

```
layout: {
  padding: {
    left: 60
  }
},
```

Please take a look on the runnable code below and see hot it works.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [10, 12, 8, 6],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 60
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        },
        {
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 0.5,
            mirror: true,
            padding: 60,
            fontColor: 'red',
            callback: v => v == 0.5 ? ['Horizontal', 'Label'] : undefined
          },
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="50"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this approach is much better than anyone's else.

Answer (score 1):

The [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. You can use the `afterDraw` hook to draw the scale label yourself directly on the canvas using [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText).

```
afterDraw: chart => {
  var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
  ctx.save();
  let yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
  let y = yAxis.bottom / 2;
  ctx.textAlign = 'left';
  ctx.font = "14px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
  ctx.fillText('Horizontal', 0, y - 8);
  ctx.fillText('Label', 0, y + 8);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

You'll also have to define some extra padding at the left of the chart to make sure, the scale label does not overlap the chart area.

```
options: {
  layout: {
    padding: {
      left: 70
    }
  },
```

Please take a look at the following runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      let yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      let y = yAxis.bottom / 2;
      ctx.textAlign = 'left';
      ctx.font = "14px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
      ctx.fillText('Horizontal', 0, y - 8);
      ctx.fillText('Label', 0, y + 8);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [10, 12, 8, 6],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 70
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="50"></canvas>
```

Comment: Seems too complicated to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in way to do this. If you want to achieve this behaviour you will have to draw it on the canvas yourself with an custom plugin